# Process return of select from database in erb view in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops

I'm trying to process a array/list that came from the database. Here's how I do it:

```
@amenities = AmenitiesAndFeatures.select("name").where(is_amenities: true).order("name ASC")

div class="e-float-left">
    <%(@amenities.each) do |amenities|%>
        <p><input type="checkbox" class="listing-check">
        <%=amenities.name%></p>
    <%end%>
</div></td>
```

I can display the data sequentially by using this code. But I want to add some logic to it.

What I want to accomplish is create a loop like for loop in .Net. How can I construct it in RoR just like this?

```
var x = amenities.length
for(int i = 0; i <= x/2;i++)
{
    <p><input type="checkbox" class="listing-check">
    amenities.name[i]</p>
}
```

I doing this on my erb view. I'm trying to pull the name column on my AmenitiesAndFeatures and process each one but inside a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this
  `x=@amenities.size/2`
 `<% @amenities.each_with_index do |amenity,i|%>`
       `<% if i <= x %>`
        `<p><input type="checkbox" class="listing-check">`
        `<%=  @amenities[i].name  %></p>`
       `<% end %>`
    `<%end%>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
half_amenities =@amenities.present? ? @amenities[0..((@amenities.length/2)-1)] : []
(half_amenities.each) do |amenities|%>
  <p><input type="checkbox" class="listing-check">
  <%=amenities.name%></p>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Where did half_amenities came from?

Comment: @sevenseacat a while ago it was just amenities. there's an error on this line. (half_amenities.each) do |amenities|%>

Comment: @ljpv14:- answer given by Rajarshi is not correct way to do though it will give same o/p that as you want.The loop will iterate over 100 times for an array of size 100 instead of 50. So it is always better to create another array with size 50.

Comment: @salil yes I just use his java code and transform it to ruby also mention that break so it will be break while it is in half many more solution is there use find_in_batches also...thank s you Salil

Comment: I prefered @Rajarshi answer because it's simple and easy to understand specially that I'm new to RoR. It is a great code for starters and the task to make this more efficient is for me to do. So kudos to both of you. Thanks!